# Why does gensim ignore underscores during preprocessing?

Tags: nltk, gensim

Going through the gensim source, I noticed the `simple_preprocess` utility function clears all punctuations except those with words starting with an underscore, `_`. Is there a reason for this?

```py
def simple_preprocess(doc, deacc=False, min_len=2, max_len=15):
    tokens = [
        token for token in tokenize(doc, lower=True, deacc=deacc, errors='ignore')
        if min_len <= len(token) <= max_len and not token.startswith('_')
    ]
    return tokens
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underscore (`'_'`) isn't typically meaningful punctuation, but is often considered a "word" character in programming and text-processing.

For example, common regular-expression syntax uses `\w` to indicate a "word character". Per https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html :

> `\w` stands for "word character". It always matches the ASCII characters
>   `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. Notice the inclusion of the underscore and digits. In
>   most flavors that support Unicode, `\w` includes many characters from
>   other scripts. There is a lot of inconsistency about which characters
>   are actually included. Letters and digits from alphabetic scripts and
>   ideographs are generally included. Connector punctuation other than
>   the underscore and numeric symbols that aren't digits may or may not
>   be included. XML Schema and XPath even include all symbols in `\w`.
>   Again, Java, JavaScript, and PCRE match only ASCII characters with `\w`.

As such, it's often used in authoring, or in other text-preprocessing steps, to connect other groups of letters/numbers that *should* be kept together as a unit. Thus it's not often cleared with other true punctuation.

The code you've referenced also does something else, different than your question about clearing punctuation: it drops word-tokens beginning with `_`.

I'm not sure why it does that; at some point that code may have be designed with some specific text-format in mind where leading-underscore tokens were semantically-unimportant formatting directives.

The `simple_preprocess()` function in gensim is just a quick-and-dirty baseline helpful for internal tests and compact beginner tutorials. It shouldn't be considered a "best practice".

Real projects should give more consideration to the kind of word-tokenization that makes sense for their data and purposes – and either look to libraries with more options, or custom approaches (which still need not be more than a few lines of Python), to implement tokenization that best suits their needs.